# Deleting new lines once the price crosses it after the line was created

Tags: line, pine-script

I have been creating new lines in pinescript that extend and want to delete them when the future price hits or crosses the line price. Any help will be appreciated.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

//@version=4
study("My RS", overlay=true)

float d = 1.0
t = time("60")
start = na(t[1]) or t > t[1]

ticker = syminfo.ticker
src=input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=open)

float d_r = na
float d_s = na

if (start)
    d_r := src + d
    d_s := src - d


line lr = na
line ls = na

// drawing r/s lines every hour
if (start) 
    lr := line.new(x1 = bar_index, y1 = d_r, x2 = bar_index - 1, y2 = d_r, extend = extend.left, color = color.red, width = 2, style = line.style_dashed)
    ls := line.new(x1 = bar_index, y1 = d_s, x2 = bar_index - 1, y2 = d_s, extend = extend.left, color = color.lime, width = 2, style = line.style_dashed)


// want to delete lines when the future price crosses the line, which is not working for me
for i = 0 to 100

    if not na(lr[i]) and close < high[i]
        line.delete(lr[i])
    if not na(ls[i]) and close < low[i]
        line.delete(ls[i])
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the entire code please? That'll help identify the problem.

Comment: Here is the code,

Comment: I don't see any changes.

Comment: if (start) 
    lr := line.new(x1 = bar_index, y1 = em_r, x2 = bar_index - 1, y2 = em_r, extend = extend.left, color = color.red, width = 2, style = line.style_dashed)

for i = 0 to 60
    if not na(lr[i]) and close < high[i]
        line.delete(lr[i])

Comment: No, I mean edit your question and put in the entire script (formatted as code). The snippet you just posted is not the entire code.

Comment: I am creating a new line on start and want to be able to delete that line when the future price tags the line

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Posted my code, hope you'll be able to help me. Thx

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the coordinate of the lines, so use inside a loop `if line.get_y1(id[i]) < close` if it true, `line.delete(id[i])`.

Is this what're you looking for?

Comment: Seems to have worked. Thanks for the help.